# Query facebook auto-generated page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm trying to understand if there's a way to query for an automatic-generated page (ex: https://www.facebook.com/pages/BMX/109551979063345).

When using a normal FQL query like this 
"select page_id from page_fan where uid = 1492838695"
the response has all my FB likes with the only exception for auto-generated pages.

There's a way to query those pages?

If not, there's a simple way to understand with an FQL query if a FB page is a "normal one" or an "auto-generated"?

Thanks all

Comment: `is_community_page` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page